# ESLint does not work in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a global install of ESLint via npm.  I can successfully lint a file from the command line, but not from within VS Code.  I have followed the instructions to use ESLint within Visual Studio Code, but it fails to work.  I do have an eslintrc file.  I have also uninstalled and reinstalled eslint a number of times.

VS Code does not produce any error message, it just does not lint the file.  I was able to use JSHint very easily, but even though the ESLint installation seems similar, it just does not work.  I am just a student, and don't know what other details may be helpful. I'm happy to provide any additional information needed.

Comment: Yes.  Several times :-0

Comment: Is your config file named exactly ".eslintrc"?
Is your config file have valid syntax?
Have you tried to install eslint locally?
ESLint extention ===  941k installs?

Comment: Have you tried to manual set "eslint.nodePath": to where the Node is?

Comment: My VS Code Setting is "eslint.nodePath": "C:\\Users\\Lynne\node_modules\\",

Inside that folder are several folders for ESLint -- eslint-config-standard, eslint-plugin-standard, etc.  Should one of those be included in the path?

I have 37 different files all named .eslintrc.  I don't know which one VS Code will use.

I have tried both global and local installations of ESLint.

Comment: Have you edited your settings.json file in visual studio code? If so, can you copy and paste the ESLINT settings into your question?